# Spring boot mac: jar not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, spring-boot

I am currently in the process of trying to containerize a spring boot application the old fashion way. I would like to build my project with a maven command, copy the jar (and its dependencies) to the container and run the Jar with embedded Tomcat.

So far, I have written a maven profile to compile my code and build a jar. Inside the jar lie all of the dependency jars. Perfect!

The unfortunate thing occurs when I try to run the jar manually through the cli. The CLI complains that there is a dependency jar missing, but after unzipping and digging through the parent jar itself, that does not seem to be the case.

Allow me to break this down further:

Here is my maven profile:

```
<profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
                <log.dir>logs</log.dir>
                <!-- updates bootstrap.properties -->
                <config.override.path>./conf</config.override.path> <!-- "file:" cannot be used with relative path (not a valid URI, y'all) -->
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Here is the command I use to run the built Jar:

```
java -jar target/the-jar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Finally, here is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: target/the-jar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/the-missing-jar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (No such file or directory)
```

I have unzipped "the-jar" only to find "the-missing-jar" right in its proper place. Not only that, the parent Jar works fine when I launch it within my IDE (IntelliJ).

Is there something that I am missing here? Should I be going with a different approach to this? I feel that I am too close to back out now.

---

Update:
Under the recommendation of a few folks, I changed my build profile. While I agree that this is a better approach, it did not change the result. I am still getting the same, specific error about a jar not found while trying to execute the uber jar.

```
<profile>
    <id>docker</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
        <log.dir>logs</log.dir>
        <!-- updates bootstrap.properties -->
        <config.override.path>./conf</config.override.path> <!-- "file:" cannot be used with relative path (not a valid URI, y'all) -->
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Don't use the `maven-assembly-plugin` use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` that takes care of everything you need. So basically you are taking the wrong approach. Spring Boot expects the class files to be in a special directory and your approach is going to generate the wrong type of file.

Comment: I added my updates in the question. This approach did not change the result. Is there anything else I can test?

Comment: Why should the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` only be part of the docker profile? That is something I don't get, you use Spring Boot and as such that should be part of the main build.

Comment: It was mainly to show the problem without sharing all of my pom file. I can confirm that this is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in manual packaging of spring boot application.

You can let `spring-boot-maven-plugin` build it properly for you.

You need to add

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

to your maven project and you'll be able to get properly packed "uber-jar" by executing:

```
mvn package
```

This is the spring-boot recommended way of building executable jars.

You can find more details including runnable example [in the documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I added my updates in the question. This approach did not change the result. Is there something else that I should be doing while launching the jar?

Comment: May be try ti run the example step by step so you’ll find out what is different.

Comment: Yeah, I have the step by step examples working. The real issue is the simple examples that official spring framework gives are too simple. Ill update this if I discover anything else